# One MySQL query to get AVG by different Groupings?

Tags: mysql, group-by, average

Wondering is there is a way to write the following in ONE MySQL query.

I have a table:
**cust_ID | rpt_name | req_secs**

In the query I'd like to get:

**the AVG req_secs when grouped by cust_ID**

**the AVG req_secs when grouped by rpt_name**

**the total req_secs AVG**

I know I can do separate grouping queries on the same table then UNION the results into one. But I was hoping there was some way to do it in one query.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear why you selected the answer that says it's not possible, when other answers to the question demonstrate that it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not.  You can group by a combination of cust_ID and rpt_name at the same time (i.e. two levels of grouping) but you are not going to be able to do separate top-level groupings and then a non-grouped aggregation at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the following would does two out of three:

```
select n,
       (case when n = 1 then cast(cust_id as varchar(255)) else rpt_name end) as grouping,
       avg(req_secs)
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2
     ) n
group by n, (case when n = 1 then cust_id else rpt_name end);
```

This essentially "doubles" the data and then does the aggregation for each group.  This assumes that `cust_id` and `rpt_name` are of compatible types.  (The query could be tweaked if this is not the case.)

Actually, you can get the overall average by using `rollup`:

```
select n,
       (case when n = 1 then cust_id else rpt_name end) as grouping,
       avg(req_secs)
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2
     ) n
group by n, (case when n = 1 then cast(cust_id as varchar(255)) else rpt_name end) with rollup
```

This works for average because the average is the same on the "doubled" data as for the original data.  It wouldn't work for `sum()` or `count()`.

Comment: +1. good to note the datatypes of `grp_ID` and `rpt_name` need to be compatible; absent any other information, looks like `rpt_name` is probably character, and grp_ID is likely integer. A small tweak to specify an explicit convert/cast from int to varchar would fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way GROUP BY works, the SQL to do this is a little tricky. One way to get the result is to get three copies of the rows, and group each set of rows separately.

```
SELECT g.gkey
     , IF(g.grp='cust_id',t.cust_ID,IF(g.grp='rpt_name',t.rpt_name,'')) AS gval
     , AVG(t.req_secs) AS avg_req_secs
  FROM (SELECT 'cust_id' AS gkey UNION ALL SELECT 'rpt_name' UNION ALL SELECT 'total') g
 CROSS
  JOIN mytable t
 GROUP 
    BY g.gkey
     , IF(g.grp='cust_id',t.cust_ID,IF(g.grp='rpt_name',t.rpt_name,''))
```

The inline view aliased as "`g`" doesn't have to use UNION ALL operators, you just need a rowset that returns exactly 3 rows with distinct values. I just used the UNION ALL as a convenient way to return three literal values as a rowset, so I could join that to the original table.